# Spark Structured Stream not loading csv files properly

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I have pipe-delimited csv files in s3 that I'm trying to load in Databricks. When reading with following code below, the file is read correctly:

```
df_test = spark.read.option("header", True).option("sep", "|").csv(s3_path)
display(df_test)
```

[image]

However, when I use Structured Streaming it reads the file as having 1 column (all the column names joined together)

```
df = spark.readStream \
            .format("cloudFiles") \
            .option("cloudFiles.allowOverwrites","true") \
            .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv") \
            .option("delimiter", "|") \
            .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", checkpoint_directory) \
            .option("cloudFiles.schemaEvolutionMode", "rescue") \
            .option("header","true") \
            .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace","false") \
            .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace","false") \
            .option("escape","\"") \
            .load(s3_path, sep='|') \
df.display()
```

[image: code snippet 2 output]
Hiding the column names for security purposes (all the data is completely fake however), but hopefully you can recognize what is going on here. The first column name is all the old column names combined - "col1,col2,col3".

I have used this logic for many other tables in my ETL process, and it is working perfectly fine. It makes me think that there is some formatting error in the csv file, but since the first code snippet reads it fine, I am completely confused right now.

Edit: Cluster timed out, and now the second code snippet is running fine after starting up the cluster again. No idea if that's even possible, so I'll leave this post up for the time being